# Flask Cassandra query LIKE

Tags: python, flask, cassandra

file models.py

```
class Document(db.Model):
    __table_name__ = 'document'

    nim = db.columns.Integer(primary_key=True)
    prodi = db.columns.Text(primary_key=True)
    tahun = db.columns.Date(primary_key=True, clustering_order="DESC")
    title = db.columns.Text(primary_key=True)
    nama_mhs = db.columns.Text()
    angkatan = db.columns.Date()
    intisari = db.columns.Text()
    kata_kunci = db.columns.Text()
    pembimbing = db.columns.Text()
    file_doc = db.columns.Text()
    password = db.columns.Text()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Document %r>' % (self.nim, self.nama_mhs, self.angkatan, self.tahun, self.prodi, self.judul, self.kata_kunci, self.intisari, self.pembimbing, self.password, self.file_doc)
```

This is the search form I created, search.html

```
<from action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="POST">
   <input name="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
   <button type="submit">
</from>
```

How to enter random text? file views.py method search()

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET','POST'])
def search()
    q1 = sesi.execute(" SELECT title FROM document WHERE title LIKE '%request.form['search']%' ")
    return render_template("title_search.html", q1=q1)
```

title_search.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% include "search_document.html" %}
<hr>
{% for data in q1 %}
<div class="col-md-8">
    <h3>Title : <a href="#">  {{ data.title }} </a></h3>
    <hr>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I get this while running

> SyntaxException: Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL
>   query] message="line 1:61 missing EOF at 'search' (... document WHERE
>   title LIKE '%request.from['[search]']...)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is much helpful after your update, the root cause is that the query string in your views.py is not valid, you'd better format the query string like this:

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET','POST'])
def search()
    q1 = sesi.execute("SELECT title FROM document WHERE title LIKE '%{}%'".format(request.form['search']))
    return render_template("title_search.html", q1=q1)
```

the query string will be like if you input the string "**Physics**" to the form in template:

```
"SELECT title FROM document WHERE title LIKE '%Physics%'"
```

Hope it will fix your issue.

Comment: Can you please post the full trace log?

Comment: I've tried to add a trace to my question, I hope you can understand the structure

Comment: I've updated the answer, hope it will work for you :)